# Blazor, Use EventArgs with Bind:Set

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, two-way-binding, blazor-hybrid

Suppose that we have a component named `MyComponent.razor` and it has a `Text` parameter and a `TimedInput` event:

```cs
[Parameter]
public string Text { get; set; } = "";

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<TimedInputEventArgs> TimedInput { get; set; }
```

The component starts a timer when the user starts typing and invokes the `TimedInput` event after a delay.

The `TimedInputEventArgs` contains the text that the user has typed and other optional information.

Other components need to bind to the Text parameter using `bind:get` and `bind:set` :

```cs
<MyComponent @bind-Text:event="TimedInput" @bind-Text:get=@(_input) @bind-Text:set="Set"></MyComponent>

@code {

private string _input = "";

   private void Set(TimedInputEventArgs args)
   {
      _input = args.CurrentText;
   }

}
```

The problem: 
`Text` is string 
The `EventCallback` is `EventCallback<TimedInputEventArgs>` 
The blazor binding mechanism expects `EventCallback<string>` to work.

The compiler-generated `BuildRenderTree` based on the above code has this line in it:

```
__builder.AddAttribute(16, "TimedInput", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<EventCallback<TimedInputEventArgs(EventCallback.Factory.Create<TimedInputEventArgs>(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, Set, (_input)))));
```

which shows an error message indicating that the `Set` method has an argument of type `TimedInputEventArgs` while it must have an argument of type `string`. (because `_input` is of type `string`)

I think it should be possible to invoke the event with whatever `EventArgs` instance.
Maybe the component wants to provide more information and not just the text that has changed so it will need some `EventArgs` instance to contain other fields too.
The blazor binding mechanism is forcing us to only be able to send the `string`.

One solution could be creating one `EventCallback` to notify the outside world about the change to the `string` and another `EventCallback` to send other things. Then invoking the two events one after the other. Which has it's own disadvantages.

Another solution is to change `Text` from `string` to `some class` that also contains the text and the extra information that is needed outside.

These solutions are problematic and not the thing that should be there.

Comment: [Polite] Sorry, I don't get your question.  What's the logical linkage between a text field and `TimedInputEventArgs`.  That's not how binding works.  You need to provide an example of your "messy" solution,  This sounds like you need to implement some sort of Notification Pattern, but without more detail, I'm only wild guessing.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The `TimedInputEventArgs` contains the new text and other optional information. The information is why it exists and the text is not directly used.

Comment: "I think it should be possible to invoke the event with whatever EventArgs instance."  You can, but you can't using Razor Binding where the in and the out are different types.  Binding is just Razor syntactic sugar.  In the real code things are wired up separately,